# Error using whitespace in MATLAB GUI label

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am writing a gui now which contains a popupmenu. This pop up menu should show different names according to cell array called titles and looks like this:

```
handles.titles={'time','velocity','angular velocity'};
```

Next, when i click on the popupmenu, i want it to plot the column which connected to this title.

so if i clicked on the 2nd popupmenu option i would like to get graph of velocity vs time.

```
handles.Parameter_Menu=hObject;
axes(handles.low_axis);
guidata(hObject,handles)
x_axis=xlim([handles.top_axis]);
set(hObject,'string',handles.titles(1:size(handles.matrix.Data,2)));
channel = get(hObject,'Value');
title_channel=handles.titles{channel}

plot(handles.(handles.titles{1}),handles.(handles.titles{channel}));
text=['graph of ' handles.titles2{channel} ' vs ' handles.titles2{1}];
title(text,'fontsize',12)
set(gca,'fontsize',10)
grid on
```

The problem occurs when i try to use title{3} because it has a space between the words.

Of course i could write it like this `angular_velocity` but then when i use it in title of the graph i recieve the letter "v" small because of the _ before it.

Is there any option to make it work with space or option to use it with _ but to avoid its effect in the title?

Comment: the problem occurs with title{3} at which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the title in plot displays exactly `_`, you can insert `\` before `_` (similar to latex):

```
handles.titles={'time','velocity','angular\_velocity'};
```

UPDATE:

since you are not only using the titles{i} for plot, but also use it as a struct's fieldname in other commands, then there is no way to have `space`, because a struct's fieldname must satisfy some conditions: `Valid field names begin with a letter, and can contain letters, digits, and underscores.`

So, you must use `titles{3} = 'angular_velocity'` to make other operations work correctly, and set `Interpreter` property of the title to be `none` to make the plot's title display `as typed` (default is TeX Markup, that's why i used `\_` for `_` above):

```
title(handle_of_something, titles{3}, 'Interpreter','none')
```

Comment: My title is made from the handle.titles{} and it says invalid field name when i write like this :    handles.(handles.titles{i})=handles.matrix.Data(:,i);